# Hamburger Menu not showing after screen 700px html/css/js front-end web dev

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I've been following along on a Youtube tutorial cloning the Microsoft website. I've been doing good so far but now I'm literally 30 seconds away from the tutorial ending, but I can't figure out why my hamburger menu isn't showing. Basically, once your screen width is < 700px, the nav bar moves off the screen to the side and a button on the top right appears to toggle, but when I press the button, the menu doesn't come back over if that makes sense.

CSS code:

```css
.main-nav ul.main-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: #ccc solid 1px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 30px;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
}

.main-nav ul.main-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.main-nav ul.main-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.main-nav ul.main-menu.show {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
<script>
    document.querySelector('.menu-btn').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('main-menu').classList.toggle('show'));
</script>
```

Comment: `main-menu` is not the correct selector in this case. Use `.main-menu` for class name selector.

Comment: can you add the HTML also

Answer (score 1):

"main-menu is not the correct selector in this case. Use .main-menu for class name selector."